# Finding if a string in one table is substring of strings in another list

Tags: mysql, loops, select, substring

I am analyzing a scrabble-like word game to find out if a block of letters placed on the board can make it impossible to place more letters, ie "lock" the game. Let me try to explain by example of 2x2 blocks:

I have build a list of valid 2x2 blocks (approx 5000 blocks). The list looks like this:

```
matrix_2x2

AA,AA
AA,AB
AA,AD
AA,AE
etc...
```

On the board "AA,AE" would look like this (the real board is 15x15):

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][A][A][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][A][E][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

I also have the complete list of valid words. It looks like this

```
dic_word

AA
AAH
AAHED
AAHING
AAHS
AAL
etc...
```

I have both lists in MySQL.

I know I could do this in code by iterate over each entry in the matrix list and make a SELECT query. It would be something like this for each matrix row:

```
SELECT COUNT(word) > 0 FROM dic_word d WHERE (INSTR(word, "AA") OR INSTR(word, "AE") OR INSTR(word, "AA") OR INSTR(word, "AE")) AND (word <> "AA" AND word <> "AB" AND word <> "AA" AND word <> "AB")
```

I was just wondering if this could be done completely in MySQL.

---

**UPDATE**

The above sql query does work nor explain very well what I am after. Let me try to clarify what I am after:

Lets assume `QX` and `QQ` and `XX` were all legal words in English, then QX,QX would be an entry in my matrix list.

As either `QX` nor `QQ` or `XX` are substrings of any English word, then QX,QX placed on the board would "lock" game (ie make it impossible to place additional letters).

I am after these lock matrices and start by looking at all valid 2x2 matrices. As we speak I am building the list of all valid 3x3 block - more than 200.000 found so far.

As a side note - I really doubt such lock matrices exists, but that is what I am checking.

Comment: maybe it's possible to do something in MySql, but given your sample data, it's not clear what results you are after... could you provide some examples?

Comment: @fthiella Please check my update above, hope it explain better what I am after

Comment: Oh.  I posted my answer before I saw your edit.  Now I'm not sure whether you're simply looking to test whether a string can be found for a given 'matrix', or are looking to find all (in?)valid 'matrices'.  In any event, I suspect the structure I propose could form a good basis for efficiently constructing such matrices.

Comment: @eggyal thanks for your effort looks very interesting - please see my "answer" which should explain better the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your existing query is that scanning for substrings is extremely inefficient.  In particular, indexes cannot be used—so a full scan of your `dic_word` table is required, and then every `word` within it must itself be individually scanned for the desired substrings.

I would instead create an indexed table of [suffixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28computer_science%29#Suffix):

```
CREATE TABLE suffixes (
  suffix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  word   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (suffix, word),
  FOREIGN KEY (word) REFERENCES dic_word (word)
);
```

One could then execute the following *extremely efficient* query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM   suffixes
WHERE (
       suffix LIKE 'AA%'
    OR suffix LIKE 'AE%'
    OR suffix LIKE 'AA%'
    OR suffix LIKE 'AE%'
      ) AND word NOT IN ('AA','AE','AA','AE')
LIMIT  1
```

Note:

- the `LIMIT` clause causes MySQL to stop searching as soon as a single result has been found;
- the resultset will either contain a single record to indicate that there is one or more possible words, or it will contain no records to indicate that there are no possible words;
- this query does not consider the space remaining on the board—for example if the only word that contains the substring is so long that it runs off the edge of the board, however that can be trivially solved by adding an additional filter on `CHAR_LENGTH(word)` which could be held within another indexed column if required;
- this optimisation does not readily extend to more complex situations, such as where there are intermittent spaces and known letters—for example `'A__DE____J__'`: whilst one can use `LIKE` to find such patterns, the index can't help beyond the initial known characters; should this be amongst your requirements, further modifications to the data structure can be made.

#### Populating and maintaining the `suffixes` table

*For the rest of this post, I use `;;` as my statement delimiter—one must configure one's client accordingly: in the [MySQL command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html), this can be achieved with the [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html) `DELIMITER ;;`.*

One can create a couple of [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-routines.html) to assist with populating the `suffixes` table:

1. Add all suffixes of a given word:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE FillSuffixes(IN p_word VARCHAR(15)) BEGIN
     DECLARE i TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
     WHILE i <= CHAR_LENGTH(p_word) DO
       INSERT IGNORE INTO suffixes
         (suffix, word)
       VALUES
         (SUBSTRING(p_word, i), p_word)
       ;
       SET i := i + 1;
     END WHILE;
   END;;
   ```
2. Add all suffixes of all words in the `dic_word` table which are not already in the `suffixes` table:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE FillAllSuffixes() BEGIN
     DECLARE w VARCHAR(15);
     DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

     DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
       SELECT word
       FROM   dic_word LEFT JOIN suffixes USING (word)
       WHERE  suffixes.word IS NULL
     ;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

     OPEN cur;

     read_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur INTO w;
       IF done THEN
         LEAVE read_loop;
       END IF;
       CALL FillSuffixes(w);
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE cur;
   END;;
   ```

One can also define [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to automatically maintain the `suffixes` table based on changes to the `dic_word` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_suffixes AFTER INSERT ON dic_word FOR EACH ROW
CALL FillSuffixes(NEW.word);;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_suffixes AFTER UPDATE ON dic_word FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.word <> OLD.word THEN
  DELETE FROM suffixes WHERE word = OLD.word;
  CALL FillSuffixes(NEW.word);
END IF;;

CREATE TRIGGER del_suffixes AFTER DELETE ON dic_word FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM suffixes WHERE word = OLD.word;;
```

Finally, to populate the table from existing records (using the procedure created above—NB, may take a short while to run):

```
CALL FillAllSuffixes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution so far.

It will go loop over all blocks of 2x2 letters (matrix) and count how many words can be placed. The result is then inserted into the table lock2. If a matrix gets a count of 0 then we have a locked game situation.

It is working but is deadly slow. The performance is acceptable for the 2x2 list but will not end in my lifetime for the 3x3 list - and im only 41 and have a reasonable fast computer.

Suggestion to improve performance are very welcome.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `wsolver`.`analyse2_2` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE analyse2_2()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a INT;
  DECLARE b VARCHAR(45);

  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Matrix FROM matrix2x2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;


      SET @w1 = SUBSTRING(a, 1, 2);
      SET @w2 = SUBSTRING(a, 4, 2);
      SET @w3 = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@w1, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(@w2, 1, 1));
      SET @w4 = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@w1, 2, 1), SUBSTRING(@w2, 2, 1));


      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @w5 FROM dan WHERE (instr(dic_word, @w1) OR instr(dic_word, @w2) OR instr(dic_word, @w3) OR instr(dic_word, @w4)) AND (dic_word NOT IN(@w1,@w2,@w3,@w4));

      INSERT INTO `lock2` (matrix, `count`) VALUES (a, @w5);


  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```